# How can I call wp-load.php in my plugin file

Tags: plugin-development, wp-load.php

I need to call wp-load.php in my plugins file but in case if I call it directly the plugin is not being accepted for wordpress repository and we are been given issue. So please guide me how can we include the "wp-load.php" file in wordpress.

Comment: Any specific condition when you need to load wp-load.php file ??

Comment: Yes I am calling a ajax file where I need to enter data in db table here I need to call wp-load.php file in that case

Comment: Plugins are already part of a loaded WordPress, you shouldn’t need to call that file.

Comment: Just use the AJAX API, no need for `wp-load.php`.

Answer (score 1):

To call wp-load.php outside wordpress, for example in your case to do some quick ajax stuff, add the following code on the top of your php file.

```
<?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-load.php');?>
```

But as @fuxia said is better to use the [WP AJAX API](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) especially if you create a plugin .

Comment: As op states in their question, your plugin will be rejected from official repository if you do this, so it's not really a solution.

Comment: This would also break on something like roots/bedrock.